# Logging signal strength in router logs?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, signal

Is it possible to to log signal strength of devices connected to Wi-Fi access point? Actually not even just connected devices, but would it be possible to intercept all wireless traffic and record the signal strength of each intercepted packet?

If it is possible, are there any routers that log this information by default, or if not by default are there any that provide options to enable such logging?

We are doing a college project on Wi-Fi triangulation, and I am kind of lost where to begin. When I search for something about measuring signal strength in access point, only results I get are about the signal strength of the actual AP itself.

If this is easier to be achieved with some particular make of router, what would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install an open-source custom firmware such as [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) and [OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start) onto most home routers. With these, you can put the wireless into monitor mode and [install a Kismet drone](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Kismet_Server/Drone) to capture and save the packets [along with signal strength info](https://kismetwireless.net/documentation.shtml).